# How to get game names through genre by using rawgpy wrapper in python?

Tags: python, api, wrapper

Here is my code for getting list of game related to racing genre I am trying to access the game name using in jupyter in python I have installed the library using anaconda prompt however when I run the code I get this error.

```
import rawgpy
from rawgpy import data_classes
results= data_classes.charts.GenreChart("racing")
game = results[0]
game.populate()`
```

```
AttributeError: module 'rawgpy.data_classes' has no attribute 'charts'
Can someone please help mw with this error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look through the source code of the package [here](https://gitlab.com/laundmo/rawg-python-wrapper).

I'm not familiar with this library, but just by reading your problem and browsing the code, I can definitely say the python module `data_classes` has no symbol/variable called `charts` in it. The way you are importing the dependencies is by trying to import everything that is in the `__init__.py` file of the import symbol, but, sadly, it seems the maintainer doesn't know how to use those file; if that variable were to exist, it would be in the init file of the [data_classes](https://gitlab.com/laundmo/rawg-python-wrapper/blob/master/rawgpy/data_classes/__init__.py) module, which is not.

You should be able to solve your problem by doing the following:

```
import rawgpy
from rawgpy.data_classes.charts import GenreChart
results= GenreChart("racing")
game = results[0]
game.populate()
```